# Как сделать <material-radio> неактивной в зависимости от условий?

Tags: angular2, angular, dart

Есть 4 группы , каждая из которых содержит 4 . Это компонент UI для теста, в котором пользователь должен выбрать оценку от 1 до 4 для каждого из 4-х вопросов ([вот аналог этого теста](http://paei.denero.ru/#test)). При этом сумма оценок не должна превышать 10 баллов. Поэтому хочу сделать неактивными те , выбор которых приведет к невыполнению этого условия (так же, как в показанном выше тесте).

Например, если в первых двух строках пользователь выбрал оценки 4 и 4, то в последующих двух блоках нужно оставить активными по 1 радио.

Вот код шаблона:

```
<div>
    <div class="skillrow">{{skill_P}}</div>
    <div class="radiorow">
        <material-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selected_P">
            <material-radio *ngFor="let item of skillScore" [value]="item">
                {{ item }}
            </material-radio>
        </material-radio-group>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="skillrow">{{skill_A}}</div>
    <div class="radiorow">
        <material-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selected_A">
            <material-radio *ngFor="let item of skillScore" [value]="item">
                {{ item }}
            </material-radio>
        </material-radio-group>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="skillrow">{{skill_E}}</div>
    <div class="radiorow">
        <material-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selected_E">
            <material-radio *ngFor="let item of skillScore" [value]="item">
                {{ item }}
            </material-radio>
        </material-radio-group>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="skillrow">{{skill_I}}</div>
    <div class="radiorow">
        <material-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selected_I">
            <material-radio *ngFor="let item of skillScore" [value]="item">
                {{ item }}
            </material-radio>
        </material-radio-group>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения Вашего вопроса я бы для начала создал модель:

```
export class Skill {
  //Имя навыка или код для дальнейшей обработки
  name: string;
  //Текущее значение
  value: number;
  //Какое значение может принять
  available: number;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = 0;
    this.available = 4;
  }
}
```

Пример сделал на Angular Material. Но логика, думаю, будет понятна. Шаблон я бы сделал в цикле, так как он у Вас все элементы однообразны:

```
<div class="skill" *ngFor="let skill of skills">
    <div class="skillrow">{{ skill.name }}</div>
    <div class="radiorow">
        <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="skill.value" (change)="onChange()">
            <mat-radio-button 
              *ngFor="let item of [1, 2, 3, 4]" [value]="item"
              [disabled]="skill.available < item"
              >
                {{ item }}
            </mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
    </div>
</div>
```

В самом компоненте инициализируем массив навыков:

```
const skillNames = ['Умение 1', 'Умение 2', 'Умение 3', 'Умение 4'];
skills: Skill[] = [];
ngOnInit() {
  skillNames.forEach((name) => {
    this.skills.push(new Skill(name));
  });    
}
```

Добавляем поля агрегаторы:

```
  total: number = 0; // содержит общее количество баллов
  touched: number = 0; // содержит количество уже выбранных опций
```

На событие изменения выбора в option создаем функцию, которая просто вызывает две другие:

```
  onChange():void {
    this.calculateTotal();
    this.checkAvailability();
  }
```

Первая из них проходит по массиву skills и вычисляет значения, которые присваиваем в агрегаторы:

```
  private calculateTotal():void {
    let total = 0;
    let touched = 0;

    this.skills.forEach((skill: Skill) => {
      total += skill.value
      if (skill.value) {
        touched++;
      }
    });
    this.total = total;
    this.touched = touched;
  }
```

Вторая вычисляет допустимые значения, проходит по массиву skills и присваивает каждому элементу поле available:

```
  private checkAvailability(): void {
    let available = 10 - this.total - (4 - this.touched);
    this.skills.map((skill: Skill) => {
      if (skill.value === 0) {
        skill.available = available + 1;
      } else {
        skill.available = available + skill.value;
      }     
    });
  }
```

Вот рабочий пример https://stackblitz.com/edit/slrv-mat-radio-conditions